# Array is null after setting data in it

Tags: swift

I have a JSON request that gets data from the Darksky API, I get the data properly and it is showing on the screen. However, When i'm trying to set the data from the array I get from the JSON call in another array, it stays empty.
This is my code:

just declaring the array:

```
var mForecastArray = [Weather]()
```

this is the function that calls the API:

```
func getForecast(){
    Weather.forecast(withLocation: "37.8267,-122.4233") { (arr) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mForecastArray = arr
            self.mTodayWeather = arr[0]
            self.mCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The weird part is that it does work, and the data do shows on screen, but still, mForecastArray seems null.

This is the API call itself:

```
static func forecast(withLocation location: String, completion: @escaping ([Weather]) -> ()){
        let url = basePath + location
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            var forecastArray: [Weather] = []
            if let data = data{
                do{
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any]{
                        if let dailyForecast = json["daily"] as? [String:Any]{
                            if let dailyData = dailyForecast["data"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                                for dataPoint in dailyData{
                                    if let weatherObject = try? Weather(json: dataPoint){
                                        forecastArray.append(weatherObject)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                completion(forecastArray)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing `nil` and which property/variable is `nil`?

Comment: mForecastArray is nil. I'm still not familiar with the queue, but maybe it happens because I set the data in mForecastArray in the DispatchQueue, so maybe it set it just there and deleting the data after it gets out of the queue? I hope you can understand me, English is not my tongue language and I have diffculty to articulate correctly.

Comment: But when/where do you see that `mForecastArray` is `nil`? Have you verified that your `forecast` method reaches the `completion(forecastArray)` line?

Comment: I tried for example to print it, and it just prints "[ ]". it does get to the completion, it is working for some reason and I do get the array of weather objects from DarkSky API.

Comment: But where/when are you printing `mForecastArray`?

Comment: I just tried printing it in ViewDidLoad after getForecast method. It's not showing in the code as I don't really need to print it, I just tested to see if it's full or not. which is not.

Comment: `getForecast` is asynchronous. The completion block is called later. So any attempt to print just after the call `getForecast` is going to happen long before the data is retrieved. Your code is fine. You just put the `print` in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you very much! where can I learn more about it? I need to use the array somewhere else in the code, but It seems empty so I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a <strike>visual</strike> asynchronous illusion.

The static method `forecast` works asynchronously.

Most likely your code looks like

```
getForecast()
print(self.mForecastArray)
```

This cannot work because the array is populated much later.

Move the `print` line into the completion handler of the static method

```
func getForecast(){
    Weather.forecast(withLocation: "37.8267,-122.4233") { (arr) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mForecastArray = arr
            print(self.mForecastArray)
            self.mTodayWeather = arr[0]
            self.mCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! where can I learn more about the asynchronous? I need to use the array somewhere else in the code, but It seems empty so I can't.

Comment: All `tasks` of URLSession run asynchronously. The data is valid in the completion handler. Move the code which depends on the array also into the completion handler or declare `getForecast` with your own completion handler.